# navbar responsive issue when resize the browser width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have an issue for the responsive navbar, when i resize the browser for the mobile view and open then close the menu button, after that make the browser full screen for the big screen view the navbar will disappear
any help for that issue

i need to add another feature to fix the navbar when scroll down but when scroll on the mobile the menu it looks messed up

below my code(on snippet)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").click(function(){
        $("nav").slideToggle(800);
    })
});
```

```css
nav{
    width: 100%;
    background: #202c45;
    padding: 0 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 18px;
}

nav h1 a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;    

}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    }

nav ul li:hover{
    background: #f2184f;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.responsive-bar{
    width: 100%;
    background: #202c45;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
}

.responsive-bar h3{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 0;
    float: left;
    color:#fff;
}
.responsive-bar h3 a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.responsive-bar h4{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background:#f2184f;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    nav{ 
        display: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .responsive-bar{
        display: block;
    }
    nav h1{
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    nav ul{
        float: none;
    }
    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1)
    }
    #full-logo{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <h1 id="full-logo"><a href="#">MyCar</a></h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</nav>
<div class="responsive-bar">
        <h3 class="brand"><a href="#">MyCar</a></h3>
    <h4 class="menu">Menu</h4>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

As per your html structure you have to add below code to your css

```
@media (min-width:768px){
    nav{
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Using this you don't have to make any changes in your html and css.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").click(function(){
        $("nav").slideToggle(800);
    })
});
```

```css
nav{
    width: 100%;
    background: #202c45;
    padding: 0 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 18px;
}

nav h1 a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;    

}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    }

nav ul li:hover{
    background: #f2184f;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.responsive-bar{
    width: 100%;
    background: #202c45;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
}

.responsive-bar h3{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 0;
    float: left;
    color:#fff;
}
.responsive-bar h3 a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.responsive-bar h4{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background:#f2184f;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    nav{ 
        display: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .responsive-bar{
        display: block;
    }
    nav h1{
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    nav ul{
        float: none;
    }
    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1)
    }
    #full-logo{
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (min-width:768px){
 nav{
     display: block !important;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <h1 id="full-logo"><a href="#">MyCar</a></h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</nav>
<div class="responsive-bar">
        <h3 class="brand"><a href="#">MyCar</a></h3>
    <h4 class="menu">Menu</h4>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Mab, if it is useful to you then please accept and upvote my answer so it is useful to others also.

Comment: please I want to add image above the navbar, and then scrolling down and the navbar stick at the top,  how can implement this

Comment: @Mab, same effect you want in mobile too?

Comment: @mab, here I'm giving you one link please check this out. Let me know if still it is not helpful to you.https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/lJoyk

Comment: but on mobile view, I don't need the image above the navbar and when i open the menu it messed up

Comment: @mab, so you don't want image in mobile view?  only desktop view, you want image above the nav. right?

Comment: yes exactly, on mobile view just I need the navbar but when I add the position:fixed; when clicking on the menu the navbar slide down but the menu still scroll up and down, and appear only when scrolling at the top

Comment: @mab, please check the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update your navigation when the window is resized. Kindly check. Hope this is helpful to you. Just made a update in jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").click(function(){
        $("nav").slideToggle(800);
    });
    
    $( window ).resize(function() {
    
      if($(window).width() > 767) {
        $("nav").slideDown(800);
      }
    });
});
```

```css
nav{
    width: 100%;
    background: #202c45;
    padding: 0 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block
}
nav h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 18px;
}

nav h1 a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;    

}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    }

nav ul li:hover{
    background: #f2184f;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.responsive-bar{
    width: 100%;
    background: #202c45;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
}

.responsive-bar h3{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 0;
    float: left;
    color:#fff;
}
.responsive-bar h3 a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.responsive-bar h4{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background:#f2184f;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    nav{ 
        display: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .responsive-bar{
        display: block;
    }
    nav h1{
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    nav ul{
        float: none;
    }
    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1)
    }
    #full-logo{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <h1 id="full-logo"><a href="#">MyCar</a></h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</nav>
<div class="responsive-bar">
        <h3 class="brand"><a href="#">MyCar</a></h3>
    <h4 class="menu">Menu</h4>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: It is slide down nav in desktop which is unnecessary.

Comment: @Bhoomi It is not necessary to apply `!important` too. Because it causes overrides and we should always avoid it :-)

Comment: Here display none is added in inline so it is necessary to add !important to override display none. 
Sometimes we have to use !important to avoid this type of issue.

Comment: @Bhoomi that is because of jquery. If it would have been added inline in HTML then it should have not been visible even in desktop view.

Comment: @AnmolSandal and Bhoomi , Either you can use slidedown or css attr display block in jquery, both are fine, but making display block !important in the css is not preferable. because the basic rule of css is not to use !important.

Comment: @AnmolSandal , using jQuery nav is slide down in desktop , which is not requirement and looks improper to end user.

Comment: @Bhoomi user end? Will user check jquery, he will do edits. Surely +1 for your answer and reply. :-) :-)

Comment: @AnmolSandal, end user will or will not check jQuery, but user can definitely see the effect of nav in desktop. :-):-).

Comment: @Bhoomi What effect will user see. Could you help it out here. It is not an issue of argument actually we are here to discuss the answers.  I would have done the same thing that you are doing in my earlier days of coding. But i cant argue or make you understand about the use of important.  

You should have used this !important unless its a third party jquery and you need to override some styles.

Comment: @AnmolSandal, the effect is of slide down on nav. Which is generated by your code. $("nav").slideDown(800); If you want to test it then move browser from mobile to web view. At that time you can see that nav is slide down. By the way I'm agree with you view on not to use !important.

Comment: @Bhoomi Sorry to say but this condition happens only when you test in browser for both mobile ipad and desktop. Although user test on diff operating system and mobile separately. Because sometimes when we check mobile view in browser the issue may not reflect but may reflect by checking in mobile. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below line of code to add image above nav and make header sticky.

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").click(function(){
        $("nav").slideToggle(800);
        $("nav").toggleClass("fixed_nav");
        $(".responsive-bar").toggleClass("addtop");
    });
}); 


$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 767) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 150) {
            $('nav').addClass('fixed-header');
        }
        else {
            $('nav').removeClass('fixed-header');
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 150) {
            $('.responsive-bar').addClass('fixed-header');
        }
        else {
            $('.responsive-bar').removeClass('fixed-header');
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1250x150">
</div>
<nav class="nav-bar">
    <h1 id="full-logo"><a href="#">MyCar</a></h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</nav>
<div class="responsive-bar">
    <h3 class="brand"><a href="#">MyCar</a></h3>
    <h4 class="menu">Menu</h4>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

.............

**CSS**

```
nav{
    width: 100%;
    background: #202c45;
    padding: 0 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 18px;
}

nav h1 a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;

}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    }

nav ul li:hover{
    background: #f2184f;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.responsive-bar{
    width: 100%;
    background: #202c45;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
}

.responsive-bar h3{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 0;
    float: left;
    color:#fff;
}
.responsive-bar h3 a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.responsive-bar h4{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background:#f2184f;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    nav{
        display: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .responsive-bar{
        display: block;
    }
    nav h1{
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    nav ul{
        float: none;
    }
    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1)
    }
    #full-logo{
        display: none;
    }
    img {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-bar.fixed_nav{
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }
    .fixed-header.addtop {
        top: 98px;
    }
}
@media (min-width:768px){
    nav{
        display: block !important;
    }
}
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```